# Editing a chart/graph and its values using PPT-VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Would it be possible to create a bar graph with the stored integers in PowerPoint without exporting those integers into a workbook?

What would be the necessary syntax to edit the data values in the mini-excel program which pop-ups when we try to edit the chart data?

[image]

```
Shapes("Chart 5").Table.Cell(3, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "222"
```

The above doesn't work.

[image: tin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following...

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 5").Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,2).Value = 222
```

Change the slide index and sheet name accordingly.

Comment: This works wonderfully! However, will there be a case that Sheet 2 will exist in the mini-excel pop-up?

Comment: It could contain more than one worksheet, depending on how many sheets were in the original workbook.  However, you'll always want to refer to the sheet containing the source data.  If you know that the source data will always be located in the first sheet (maybe that's the only sheet), you can refer to the worksheet by index, instead of name (ie.  `...Worksheets(1).Cells(,2).Value = 22`).